# How to migrate 100 plus SVN repositories to a new server(windows) from windows server?

Tags: svn, svnadmin

i have to move some 100 plus individual svn repos to a different windows server. I don't want to dump each repo and load it on to the new server as it takes a lot of time. can anyone please suggest some other solution which will save time. Also once I move my repos to new server do i have to create a new repository for each single old repository or will the svn installed on the new server detect and track the newly moved repositories?
We are using Collabnet Subversion Edge on both the old and new servers. please advice. you help is greatly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

And what type of server are you using? Is it Apache http?

If you're moving the repositories from one Windows machine to another, *it should be safe* to simply move the repository directories themselves from one system to the other, and you don't have to do a dump and load. This is especially true if both servers are running the same version of Subversion.

However, if this was Unix, I would do a dump and load, but only because I can easily write a shell script to do this. I guess if you had Cygwin installed, you could write a shell script. How is your PowerShell?

As for configuring, are you using Apache HTTP? If so, you can use the `SVNParentPath` to simply point to the parent path where all the repositories are stored. Here's ours. Any repository located in the `/opt/cm/svn_repos` directory is served as `http://machine/src/<reposName>`:

```
<Location /src>
    DAV svn
    SVNParentPath /opt/cm/svn_repos
    SVNListParentPath on
    AuthType basic
    AuthName "Our Repository"
    AuthBasicProvider ldap
    AuthzLDAPAuthoritative off
    AuthLDAPURL "ldap:..."
    AuthLDAPBindDN "..."
    AuthLDAPBindPassword "..."
    Require valid-user
</Location>
```

Comment: Hi David, I have a similar issue. As specified, I moved the repository directories from one system to another. However both the servers are running different version of subversion server.Both the subversion servers are in windows machine. Please help me in resolving the issue

Comment: You may be able to do a [`svnadmin upgrade`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svnadmin.c.upgrade.html) on the repositories. However, you should backup the repos first, and a word of warning: Newer versions of SVN use very different formats for their repos, so an `svnadmin upgrade` may not always work, but I would give it a try. A dump and load isn't difficult, but it can take some time depending upon the size of the repositories. However, even a large repo doesn't take that long to dump and load. It could be done over night in necessary.